# Marketing Cloud Preference center with Sendable Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, preference-center

We're trying to rearchitect Marketing Cloud implementation in my organization. In the current set up, we have an external Preference center database (SQL Server). A User updates preferences on an externally developed-open source hosted web page to update preferences. These preferences are then synced to Marketing Cloud on a preference Data Extension.

We are evaluating whether to replace external Preference Center with Marketing Cloud Preference Center but I find a lot of conflicting information:

1. SFDC documentation says that for >500K contacts use Data Extensions and Standard Profile Center and Subscription Center isn't available to Data Extension approach. 
   a)Does that mean if you Data extensions in Email Studio we can't use Preference Center?
   b) If we use Synchronized Data Extension using Marketing Cloud Connect , can it leverage default Preference Center?

Also, want to point out that reason for having an external preference center was so we can support any other customer interacting platforms e.g. we have an external website for purchasing orders, an external app where customer can manage account and bill payment etc.